# bootmgfw.efi not able to load further after being downloaded by network during PXE, but loads fine if loaded from disk

Tags: bootloader, efi, grub2, firmware, bootmgr

I am trying to load into winpe using bootmgfw.efi, it is being downlaoded by TFTP download looks fine, but after downloading, it is stuck at a blank screen and TFTP log says downloaded is the last thing. but the same thing loads when bootmgfw.efi is loaded from local disk. trying to load using menu from grub2

Comment: Can you use [wimboot](https://ipxe.org/wimboot) ?

Comment: i guess no i have to load using bootmgfw.efi as it is used widely in other projects

Comment: i am able to download and load bootmgfw.efi , but once after downloading bootmgfw.efi i am getting BlInitializeLibrary Failed 0x0000017 error

Comment: I would guess something is wrong with PXE image or the boot process, but I can't go further than this.

Comment: @harrymc when bootmgfw.efi is loaded i am getting BlInitializeLibrary Failed 0xc0000017 error on client screen

Comment: It might be an incorrect passage of control to bootmgfw.efi. See [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351646/17660).

Comment: @harrymc that is for loading bootmgfw.efi from local partition, my case from net(TFTP)

Comment: I meant the error, not the context.

Comment: @harrymc since the example is using bootmgfw.efi from his local partition he used (hd0,2). what can be used for net/TFTP?

Comment: I can't help you with that, since I have no knowledge of how your BIOS handles PXE, but it seems to me that it either chain-loads badly bootmgfw.efi, or that the file itself is damaged/unsuitable.